# vuejs-paginator example html markup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a pretty daft question re: [vuejs-paginator](http://hootlex.github.io/vuejs-paginator/) but I am having a hard time getting to run this example (I am a backend dev here).

So, I have on my head:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuejs-paginator/2.0.0/vuejs-paginator.js"></script>
```

Then as described in the page, I have:

```
      <script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data () {
            return {
              // The resource variable
              animals: [],
              // Here you define the url of your paginated API
              resource_url: 'http://hootlex.github.io/vuejs-paginator/samples/animals1.json'
            }
          },
          components: {
            VPaginator: VuePaginator
          },
          methods: {
            updateResource(data){
              this.animals = data
            }
          }
        });            
      </script>
```

Now, what the F I should have in my HTML, I have no clue, and the author seems to say, I use:

```
    <v-paginator resource_url="api/animals" @update="updateResource"></v-paginator>
```

but, this I think is just for the pagination. What shoud the `app` element contain and where is it? The docs dont seem to show this? he author then shows some `random` markup:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="animal in animals">
    {{ animal.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where should this go? Should I have an `app` div element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add content to your app by adding it to the `template` key:

```js
<script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data () {
            return {
              // The resource variable
              animals: [],
              // Here you define the url of your paginated API
              resource_url: 'http://hootlex.github.io/vuejs-paginator/samples/animals1.json'
            }
          },
          components: {
            VPaginator: VuePaginator
          },
          methods: {
            updateResource(data){
              this.animals = data
            }
          },
          template: `
             <div>
                <ul>
                   <li v-for="animal in animals">
                     {{ animal.name }}
                   </li>
                 </ul>
                 <v-paginator :resource_url="resource_url" @update="updateResource"></v-paginator>
             </div>
          `
        });            
      </script>
```

Something like that.

You also need an initial `<div id="app"></div>` in your html. This is the element where Vue will mount the app and load the content.

**EDIT**

The plugin uses `this.$http` which requires some kind of dependency that it doesn't specify.

I have made an alteration in the following `codepen` and it works properly now:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dream-zngzt

Comment: Firstly thanks for this. I tried to replicate what you have said, but I still see no `animals` as described in the example. I just see disabled `Previous` and `Next` pages along with ` Page of `.. VERY annoying!!!! Any ideas why the animal list is not being rendered?

Comment: This line looks odd `<v-paginator resource_url="api/animals"`. I think it should be `<v-paginator :resource_url="resource_url"`. I'll update my post

Comment: I too tried your sugestion. I used `<v-paginator :resource_url="resource_url" @update="updateResource"></v-paginator>` still no joy. It CANT be this difficult!

Comment: thanks, that would be inetresting - I definately cant seem to get it to work - but I am no vueJS dev :(

Comment: I wonder if `<div id="app"></div>` should be inside `Vue template` code?

Comment: Well. It seems the plugin is broken or requires some external dependency that it doesn't make clear. I copied the code over to the codepen and fixed it. Now it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dream-zngzt

Comment: do you think I should continue using this plugin? I see that you have made this to work on CP - however, I am using just the CDN - should I just movethe template outside of the Vue script?

Comment: The plugin is small. I would avoid the CDN and make my own components locally using the code from the codepen I created. You just need `VuePaginator.vue` and `utils.js`. Just a suggestion of course :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204847/discussion-between-t-short-and-johnj).

Comment: OK makes sense 0 ket me try how to do it locally (I normally work with C and Python, so this is new to me). Anyways, Meery XMas :) I have accepted your answer.